# Checking if a user has a certain role

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I use mongoDb in my express server and store the user information like this:

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: {type: String, required: true ,  index: { unique: true } },
    isActive: {type:Boolean, default:false},
    signUpDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    roles: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Role"
        }
    ]
});
```

With Role having a simple single field : name.

To find out if a user is an admin for example I do:

```js
User.findById(req.SecureUserId).populate('roles').exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
        }
        for(let roles of user.roles){
            if(roles.name === 'admin'){
                next();
                return;
            }
        }
```

However, this seems like something I can better query to my database ?
How would I do this in mongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.aggregate()` to "join" single user with his role and then run `$match` to verify if there's any role named `admin`. If particular user doesn't have such role then aggregation will return an empty array:

```
User.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: req.SecureUserId } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "roles",
            localField: "roles",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "roles"
        }
    },
    { $match: { "roles.name": "admin" } }
]).exec((err, user) => {
    if(user.length === 1){
        next();
    }
})
```

Comment: Be sure if secureuserid is a string to first wrap it in a mongoose object id ! Got stuck there for a little bit